# When using dynamic in c#, column names returned of first tables instead of second table

Tags: c#, dynamic

There is a stored Procedure in oracle which returns table data based on a value (table name). It works fine but for one of the few instances if I pass `tableName1` it give correct data and second time `tableName2`  it give correct data but with columns of `tableName1`.

Is something wrong with my code or dynamic call site caching is the problem?

When I tested the stored Procedure from Toad with same instance it return correct data with proper headers.

Consider each method in different layer (controller > Business > Data Layer).

```
   //controller
   [AcceptVerbs("Get")]        
    public IHttpActionResult GetTableData(string tableName)    
    {
          return Ok(GetTableData(tableName));
    }

     //business layer
    public IList<dynamic> GetTableData(string tableName)
    {
         //using petaPoco ORM
         IList<dynamic> result = GetData<dynamic>GetData("StoredProc_NAME",new {sp_param_tableName = tableName});
         return result;
    }

    //data layer
    List<TEntity> GetData<TEntity>(string sqlScript, params object[] param)
    {
         using (PetaPoco.Database PpDBObject= GetPetaPocoDatabaseObject())
         {
             return PpDBObject.Fetch<TEntity>(sqlScript, param);
         }
    }
```

Comment: or something wrong with TEntity/PetaPoco

Comment: It's difficult to help when you don't show the actual code you are executing. What you have shown will not compile so you must be doing something else.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Updated the sample code, hope it helps. PetaPoco is micro-ORM

Comment: when I stop and restart visual studio then give second table name it gives correct headers.

Comment: Original problem remain same...

Comment: "result" has list of dictionary column names and values, which has key as first table column name and value of second table when passing second table name.

Comment: There are very few tables output correct header and data out of 20 tables

Comment: commenting the  /*{sp_param_tableName = tableName} */ while pass this to PetaPoco solved the issue. The library is caching the input, with this fix it solved the problem.